# How to find the greatest value of this expression?

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, fractions, maxima-minima

"This expression" is

> $$\frac{5\sin^2\alpha+4\cos^2\alpha}{4\cos^2\beta+5\sin^2\beta}.$$
>   The answer is $1.25$

I used simple steps to simplify this, but couldn't find the greatest value, since it has $2$ kinds of angles. So how to find that?

Comment: The expression is identical to $\dfrac{9-\cos (2 a)}{9-\cos (2 b)}$ thus if $\cos 2\alpha=-1$ and $\cos2\beta=1$ the fraction is maximum $\dfrac{10}{8}=\dfrac{5}{4}=1.25$. That is when $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\beta=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note also that you can write your expression as
$$\frac{\sin^2\alpha + 4(\overbrace{\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha}^1)}{\sin^2\beta + 4(\underbrace{\sin^2\beta + \cos^2\beta}_1)}$$
$$=\frac{4+ \sin^2\alpha}{4+ \sin^2\beta}$$

A ratio of positive numbers increases if the numerator increases, or if the denominator decreases. Since $0\leq\sin^2\theta\leq 1$, this means that the largest value of the numerator is $4+1=5$ and the smallest value of the denominator is $4+0=4$. So the largest value of the fraction is $\frac54$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{5\sin^2\alpha+4\cos^2\alpha}{4\cos^2\beta+5\sin^2\beta}=\frac{4+\sin^2\alpha}{4+\sin^2\beta}\leq\frac{4+1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $\sin\alpha=1$ and $\sin\beta=0$, which says that the answer is $\frac{5}{4}.$

Done!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\mathrm{max}\{ 5\sin^2\alpha + 4\cos^2\alpha \} = 5$ and $\mathrm{min}\{ 4\cos^2\beta + 5\sin^2\beta \} = 4$

Comment: cuts through the maze...

Answer (score 1):

Setting
$$
x=\cos^2\alpha,\quad y=\cos^2\beta,
$$
we have
$$
\dfrac{5\sin^2\alpha+4\cos^2\alpha}{4\cos^2\beta+5\sin^2\beta}=\dfrac{5(1-x)+4x}{4y+5(1-y)}=\dfrac{5-x}{5-y}=f(x,y)
$$
since 
$$
0\le x,y\le 1,
$$ 
we have
$$
4\le 5-x,5-y\le 5
$$
and therefore
$$
\dfrac{4}{5}\le f(x,y)\le \dfrac{5}{4}.
$$
Notice that
$$
f(0,1)=\dfrac{5}{4},
$$
thus
$$
\max_{\alpha,\beta}\dfrac{5\sin^2\alpha+4\cos^2\alpha}{4\cos^2\beta+5\sin^2\beta}=\max_{0\le x,y\le 1}f(x,y)=f(0,1)=\dfrac54=1.25
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Maximize the numerator and minimize the denominator (they depends on different variables).
As regards the numerator note that
$$n(\alpha):=5\sin^2\alpha+4\cos^2\alpha=\sin^2+4\alpha\leq 5=n(\pi/2).$$
Can you handle the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

since numerator and denominator depend on different parameters maximize the numerator and minimize the denominator.
$$
\alpha=\pi/2; \,\,\,\,\,\,\beta=0
$$
to get $5/4$ as maximum value

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac { 5\sin ^{ 2 } \alpha +4\cos ^{ 2 } \alpha  }{ 4\cos ^{ 2 } \beta +5\sin ^{ 2 } \beta  } =\frac { \sin ^{ 2 } \alpha +4 }{ 4+\sin ^{ 2 } \beta  } =\frac { 1+4 }{ 4 } =1.25$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your term is equivalent to $${\frac { \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}-5}{ \left( 
\cos \left( \beta \right)  \right) ^{2}-5}}
$$